# Moleculer - how to mockup method inside jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, moleculer

To mockup using Jest, we usually use `jest.spyOn`. But how to mockup `method` inside Moleculer service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwrite it after the service created in your test case.
Example:

```
describe("Test MyService", () => {
    const broker = new ServiceBroker({ logger: false });
    const service = broker.createService(MyService);

    // Mock my method in service instance
    service.myMethod = jest.fn();

    it("should call myMethod", () => {
        service.doSomething();
        expect(service.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```